# 'Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to int' when inserting BIGINT into BIGINT column

Tags: sql-server, integer, bigint

I'm trying to insert a `BIGINT` value into a `BIGINT` column, even though I think it should work.but instead it gives me the following error:

> *Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 3 Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.*

The create script for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Bod
(
    Voorwerp                BIGINT                  NOT NULL,
    Bodbedrag               DECIMAL(8, 2)           NOT NULL,
    Gebruiker               VARCHAR(50)             NOT NULL,
    BodDag                  DATE                    NOT NULL,
    BodTijdstip             TIME                    NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT pk_bod PRIMARY KEY(Voorwerp, Bodbedrag)  
);
```

And the `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO Bod 
VALUES (110753735651, 14.90, '01relax', GETDATE(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

[Here are the things related to the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ttc8i.png)

EDIT: HOLY SHIT I'm dumb it's the time(7). I completely missed that. It works now, sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: It *does* work -- I've tried it. Make sure to explicitly specify column names in your `INSERT`, rather than relying on what you *think* is the column order, and verify that the table has no poorly-written triggers on it.

Comment: No repro. Is there perhaps a trigger on that table? Also, if you want to record a particular point in time, including the day it happened on, it's better to store that as a single `datetime2` column rather than separate columns.

Comment: Are you executing the Insert statement in SSMS or via a custom App?

Comment: In addition to what @Damien pointed out: `GETDATE()` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` return the same result, that is, a `DATETIME` with limited precision. It makes no sense to mix them (and there is no function that returns only the time). I'd say avoid `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` unless you must be ANSI compatible, since `GETDATE()` makes it clear it's a function. `SYSDATETIME()` is the one with enough precision for a `TIME`/`DATETIME2` (and if you don't need more precision, be sure to explicitly specify it, e.g. `[DATE]TIME(0)`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have tried it again, explicitly stating the column names but it doesn't work, stating the same error. It doesn't have any triggers for as far as I can tell. (I clicked on the 'triggers' folder in SSMS)

Comment: @pacreely I'm using SSMS for this statement

Comment: [Can't repro on an empty database](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/78f09/1). I'd ask for your SQL Server version, but that really shouldn't make a difference. Check for weirder things, like being in a non-default schema (rather than `dbo`), being in the wrong database, or being on the wrong server.

Comment: Try adding the column list - perhaps the columns in the table are not in the order your query assumes.